# Local apache server on PC - PHP cannot connect to other remote server

Tags: php, apache

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in a VM (referring to as PC A).
I installed a local apache server on my PC A with php5 for developing. Now I want to access the remote server from my php-Script running on PC A to one of my production servers S. In fact I am calling some Web-Api-URL on Server S.
Server S is reachable from the internet and I can also connect via SSH from PC A to Server S. The installed application on Server S is also reachable.

The PHP script etc is correct and works. I could debug this to the point where it should connect to the remote server. It doesn't.

Do I need to add some config to php/apache to allow connections to the remote server?

Comment: Can you do a wget to your web-api-url from your PC A and tell us what is the result ?
And share some php, the part doing the call of the api ?

Comment: That is not the problem. Accesing the url from PC A via Firefox etc is no problem. The PHP thing is just some CURL. However, when I look into Wireshark I see that no request is made from the PHP script. It executes and does not give an Error. The specific method which does the CURL thing is definitely called.
Maybe I am just missing the curl libs? I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: It's a possibility, it's php5-curl package.  
Have you check you display_error config ? And the logs ? php, apache and syslog ?

Comment: @Nicolas It was the CURL libs. I installed them and now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just missing the CURL libs. 
After installing `php5-curl` it works all fine.
And I did not get any error messages, because  `display_erros` was not activated.